# Store output of a remote ssh command to a local variable in a loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, ssh, echo

I try to run a command for a list of hosts and then store the output in a variable in a loop. I also created an array to associate ip/hostname as my command will only accept IP address as an argument but I want to use hostname and channel name in variable name. My code looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP="10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.4 10.0.0.5"
CHANNEL="1 2 3 " 
USERNAME="username" 
SCRIPT_HOST="myscript_host" 
HOME_DIR="/home/myuser" 
SCRIPT_DIR=$HOME_DIR/scripts 
COMMAND="sudo /path_to_my_remote_script" 
SSH="ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=10 -l $USERNAME"

declare -A array
array[10.0.0.1]="host1"
array[10.0.0.2]="host2"
array[10.0.0.3]="host3"
array[10.0.0.4]="host4"
array[10.0.0.5]="host5"

for ip in ${IP} ; do
for channel in ${CHANNEL} ; do

my_variable_name_$(${array[$($ip)]})_$c=$($SSH "$COMMAND -i $ip |grep -i \"ipv4 count\"|awk {print \$4}'") 

echo my_variable_name_$(${array[$($ip)]})_$c
done;done
```

When I execute my script I receive an error message like:

./test_array.sh: line 20: 10.0.0.1: command not found
./test_array.sh: line 20: array: bad array subscript

I can guess it's a syntax error but can't figure out. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I changed it to:

my_variable_name_${array[$($ip)]}_$c=$($SSH "$COMMAND -i $ip | grep -i \"ipv4 count\" | awk ' {print \$4}'")

echo my_variable_name_${array[$($ip)]}_$c

done; done 

But again same error.


./test_array.sh: line 20: 10.0.0.1: command not found
./test_array.sh: line 20: array: bad array subscript

Comment: As much as I understand, it didn't like either right side of the assignment it takes -i $ip as a separate command but it should be a parameter of $COMMAND command.
I want to see a variable name such as my_variable_name_10.0.0.1_1 my_variable_name_10.0.0.1_2 my_variable_name_10.0.0.1_3 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rewrite that as

```
declare -A array
array[10.0.0.1]="host1"
array[10.0.0.2]="host2"
array[10.0.0.3]="host3"
array[10.0.0.4]="host4"
array[10.0.0.5]="host5"

channels="1 2 3"
script=/path_to_my_remote_script
cmd=(ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=10 -l username myscript_host)

for ip in "${!array[@]}" ; do
    for channel in $channels ; do
        varname=my_variable_name_${array[$ip]}_$channel
        echo $varname

        remote_script="sudo $script -i $ip | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/ipv4 count/ {print \$4}'"
        out=$( "${cmd[@]}" "$remote_script" )

        declare "$varname=$out"
    done
done
```

- the `declare` command can assign to dynamically created variable names without having to use eval
- you don't need to store the array keys in a separate variable
- storing commands in arrays is more robust ([ref](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050))
- if you're calling `awk`, you don't need to use `grep` first
- in my opinion, too many variables can actually reduce readability

On second thought, I'd use another array to store the output, using a pseudo-multi-dimensional key:

```
declare -A my_variable_name
for ip in "${!array[@]}" ; do
    for channel in $channels ; do
        remote_script="sudo $script -i $ip | awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/ipv4 count/ {print \$4}'"
        my_variable_name[$ip,$channel]=$( "${cmd[@]}" "$remote_script" )
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
my_variable_name_$(${array[$($ip)]})_$c= ...
```

the `$(${array{...}})` syntax is the issue.  Essentially the `$(...)` wrapping the array is trying to call a command.  Remove the `$(` and corresponding `)`.  Likewise in the `echo` statement below that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this through `eval` and to avoid complicated/unreadable statements I would use a temporary variable:

```
vname=my_variable_name_${array[$ip]}_$c
tmp=$($SSH ...)
eval $vname=\$tmp
```

To see what's going on, you can add a

```
set -x
```

before the statements or call it as `bash -x your-script`

Comment: I added some more lines to simplify debugging besides bash -x
    SUF1=`echo ${array[$ip]}`
    SUF2="$channel"
    vname=my_variable_name_${SUF1}_${SUF2}
    tmp=$( $SSH "$COMMAND -i $ip -c $channel |grep -i \"ipv4 count\" |awk '{print \$4}'" )
    eval $vname=\$tmp
    done;done

Comment: + for ip in '${IP}'
+ for channel in '${CHANNEL}'
++ echo host1
+ SUFFIXE1=host1
+ SUFFIXE2=1
+ vname=my_variable_name_host1_1
++ ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=10 -l username my_script_host 'sudo /path_to_my_remote_script -i 10.0.0.1 -c 1 | grep -i "ipv4 count" | awk '\''{print $4}'\'''

And it is stuck here, and I  can break it with ctrl+c and it will execute next value in inner loop consecutively for 3,5, and 7 values.

I think it didn't like somehow escaping sequence in SSH command.

Comment: there seems to be a misplaced `'` in your ssh command (nearly at the end)